# Joomla URL rewrite for component without a redirect

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, joomla

I have a Joomla component “com_foo” which works fine when called via...

`http://my.joomla.site/index.php?option=com_foo&id=1234`

... but I need the URL be in the following format:

`http://my.joomla.site/getfoo/1234`

The closest I can get is with the following .htaccess rewrite which causes a redirect:

```
RewriteEngine On

# My Rule
RewriteRule ^getfoo/(.*)$ /index.php?option=com_foo&id=$1 [R=301,L]

#  Joomla rules
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

I can’t seem to figure out how to make the same thing work “internally” w/o the redirect. So in my example above what happens is:

```
[1] GET http://my.joomla.site/getfoo/1234 REDIRECTS TO
[2] GET http://my.joomla.site/index.php?option=com_foo&id=1234 RENDERS PAGE
```

What I need is

```
[1] GET http://my.joomla.site/getfoo/1234 RENDERS PAGE
```

Almost everything I try results in a 500 error. I feel like it's got to be something simple but it's got me beat at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you could probably get this working using the .htaccess file, by seperating the SEF logic from the component code you open yourself up to a management nightmare down the road. Joomla does however, provide a means to manage SEF url parsing and generation with your custom components.  By placing the file router.php in the root of your component's folder, Joomla will automatically use this file to both generate and parse SEF urls.  Although the link below does provide detailed information on how to implement, I've found reverse engineering core components router.php file helped me tremendously.

http://docs.joomla.org/Supporting_SEF_URLs_in_your_component

Comment: Thank you! I thought there was probably a better way. I haven't completely solved this yet as I'm having problems with parsing route and the hidden menus, but I'm close.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /index\.php\?option=com_foo&id=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /getfoo/%2\? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^getfoo/(.*)$ /index.php?option=com_foo&id=$1 [L]
```

The above will:

- Redirect `http://my.joomla.site/index.php?option=com_foo&id=1234` to `http://my.joomla.site/getfoo/1234` and show the information from the `http://my.joomla.site/index.php?option=com_foo&id=1234` page

When viewing

- `http://my.joomla.site/getfoo/1234` will display the information from the `http://my.joomla.site/index.php?option=com_foo&id=1234` page

Change the `R=302` to `R=301` when you are sure the redirect works.

Comment: Thank you for this, this definitely helps me see a better way to approach the whole thing. Unfortunately in my setup this is resulting in another 500. I've tried changing things around a little and I'm ending up in either 500's or redirect loops. I am also going to try Brian Bolli's recommendation to work this into the router and if that works I won't need to do the rewriting.